# Searching Facebook for a combination of hashtags

Tags: facebook, facebook-search

I can search public Facebook posts using a single hashtag with a search such as `https://www.facebook.com/hashtag/foo` or `https://www.facebook.com/hashtag/bar`.

But how can I search posts that include *both* hashtags `foo` *and* `bar`?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, neither of the ways I've seen this sort of thing done on other sites (e.g., `https://www.facebook.com/hashtag/foo+bar` or `https://www.facebook.com/hashtag/foo/bar`) work.

It looks like the best you can do is manipulate the search string you get if you put multiple hash tags in the search field and submit. Like so:

```
https://www.facebook.com/search/str/%23foo%20%23bar/keywords_top
```